# StackExchangeRedis.Extensions.Core .net core

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, c#-4.0, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a Redis Cluster with a password created in aws. I am not able to connect to that cluster without password in redis insight tool. But when i locally debug my code, i am able to connect to redis even without using password. Any idea ?